# Can we clean yum cache files manually?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, yum

I am using Redhat 7 while running `yum update` I am getting `Bus error (core dumped)` error.

After troubleshooting I found that `/` was full because of `/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7server/rhel-x86_64-server-7/gen` folder.

Inside this folder below files contains GB of data.

[image]

I tried `yum clean all` command to clean up the space but it is not working.

Can I manually delete these files?

Manual delete will cause any problem to yum ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After successful installation, packages should be deleted from the yum cache.
You should check in the file `/etc/yum.conf`, whether the `keepcache` setting
is `1` instead of `0`.

The RedHat post
[Maybe you want: rm -rf /var/cache/yum](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/3195102) 
says that
the command `yum clean all` gives the impression that enabled and disabled/removed
repos are cleaned but in reality, performs only these tasks:

- clean all cache from enabled repos
- remove all data from unknown repos
- preserve cache of disabled/removed repos

The fix in
[RHBA-2017:2295](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2017:2295)
should have added a reminder for this command saying:

> Maybe you want: rm -rf /var/cache/yum, to also free up space taken by orphaned data from disabled or removed repos

In any case, whatever your situation, you can issue the recommended command:

```
rm -rf /var/cache/yum
```

Comment: In no case it is safe to start typing anything `rm -rf`. Depending on when the cat jumps on my desk scaring the hell out of me, my trembling pinky hits the enter at either `/` or `/var`

Comment: @YoYo That's a valid concern.  I address it by typing `xxrm -rf /var/cache/…`, then staring at the command for a while to make absolutely positively sure it's correct, then taking a deep breath, deleting the leading `xx`, *then* hitting Return.

Comment: A colleague and I just discovered that significant space was being tied down (3% of our disk, which meant almost 2 gig) by some database files and other metadata, even though `keepcache` was set to 0.  `rm -rf` fixed it.

Comment: @SteveSummit lol - but I probably start doing it that way. Plus why not splitting the space bar and having an enter button under one of our stronger thumbs.

Answer (score 3):

Manual deletion is quite safe and will not cause problems with `yum`. This is fine:

```
rm -rf /var/cache/yum
```

You can also check [this post](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/clear-disk-space-centos) on other steps that may help in clearing disk space.