# Is there any strategy for *really* disabling systemd services? Some start up even after disabling with systemctl

Tags: systemd

It seems like whenever I try to disable a systemd service, the service finds some way to reenable itself. The most recent example has been PackageKit, which I have discovered is the source of the problem I asked about in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1733947). If I run this:

```
systemctl disable packagekit
```

And then for a few days my disk stays stable, but after a few days, PackageKit reenables itself, and runs, and fills `/var/cache/yum` back up again, pegging my disk at 100%.

I’m not asking about PackageKit specifically; really I’m trying to understand how systemd service deactivation is supposed to work.

Is there any general-purpose way to say, “Disable this service, and also disable any way of automatically reenabling it?” Or is my only choice to outright delete the package that I don’t want running?

---

UPDATE: Part of my question was misguided: It's not `systemctl disable`'s job to make sure a service never runs no matter what; all `systemctl disable` does is say that the service shouldn't run automatically on boot.

Per a suggestion in user1686's answer, I tried

```
busctl --activatable | grep -i packagekit
```

and got

```
org.freedesktop.PackageKit      - -     -    (activatable) -       -
```

so that may well indicate what sort of thing was kicking it off (if not at boot).  But I didn't think to try `busctl tree` before moving on to the next step.

Again per user1686's suggestion, I tried

```
systemctl mask packagekit
```

and that seems to have done the trick — whatever was starting that thing up before, isn't starting it up any more.
I don't know if this would be considered an ugly or brute-force or dangerous solution; I don't know if it will work forever, but it seems to be working for now.

Comment: FWIW, some things that get installed via packages nowadays have nothing to with systemd service controls. You _might_ be able to set a value, but it operates on another bit of criteria somewhere. I believe the answer here is ultimately this is a “case-by-case” issue than anything else.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

"Disabling" a service in systemd is mostly equivalent to "removing from runlevel" in other init systems (it removes the service from 'multi-user.target' dependency tree). Most of the time, it means the service will no longer be *explicitly* started during boot.

But it does not mean that the service can't be started in *other* ways – e.g. you can still manually `systemctl start` a disabled service, just like you could `/etc/init.d/foo start` it in the past.

Some services are set up to be started in more indirect ways than simple "on boot", but which could still trigger its startup while the system is still booting:

- They might be started as an explicit dependency of some other service. If that other service happens to start on boot, this one will get started too.

  Try `systemctl list-dependencies --reverse <unit>` to see if anything wants or requires that service.
- They might have an associated `.socket` unit that will start the service "on demand" as soon as a client attempts to connect. (If there is a connection attempt during boot, it will certainly *look like* the service was started "on boot".)

  The service's `systemctl status` should show if it's activated by a socket or timer unit – those units can also be stopped & disabled.
- Similarly to on-demand socket activation, services might be "D-Bus activated" by a program trying to speak to them through the message bus. (For example, it's possible that packagekitd would be started because gnome-software tried to query it around the time of your logon.)

  Often such services have an Alias that "systemctl disable" removes, preventing unwanted D-Bus activation of a disabled service – but that's not always implemented correctly.<sup>1</sup>

However, beyond that, systemd does not automatically *enable* units that you've disabled. If you see that a unit is explicitly enabled again (e.g. the symlink within `multi-user.target.wants` has been re-created), then it must have been triggered by something external.

- Some distributions use systemd *presets* to re-enable or re-disable units according to their overall policy, by invoking `systemctl preset` every time some relevant package is updated. (See the [systemd.preset](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.preset.html) manual page.) If you create a custom preset that tells systemctl to always disable the service, it will override the distro's policy:

  ```
  (/etc/systemd/system-preset/00-steve.preset)

  disable packagekit*.service
  ```
- Some distributions have a direct call to `systemctl enable` hardcoded in their post-upgrade scripts. In this case, *masking* the unit would make systemd behave as if it doesn't exist at all – it can no longer be enabled, started, or otherwise touched:

  ```
  % systemctl disable --now packagekit
  % systemctl mask packagekit
  ```

  Your distribution's package manager may also have an option to skip extracting certain files entirely, so that they would *literally* no longer exist as far as systemd is concerned – e.g. pacman:

  ```
  (/etc/pacman.conf)

  [options]
  NoExtract = usr/lib/systemd/system/packagekit*
  ```

---

#### D-Bus activation

<sup>1</sup> If your service is listed in `busctl --activatable`, try using e.g. `busctl tree` on its bus name and see if that makes the service start up.

If talking to org.freedesktop.PackageKit1 (or whatever name) does cause a disabled systemd service to start, this generally means that the D-Bus `.service` file is pointing to the wrong systemd `.service` file (yes, those are different things), *or* it's not pointing to a systemd service at all (causing dbus-daemon to spawn the service directly).

In the former case, you can mask the systemd .service and dbus-daemon will no longer be able to start it. In the latter case, you'll have to either override the D-Bus .service via `/usr/local/share/dbus-1` or make your package manager not extract it at all (as dbus-daemon doesn't have an equivalent to enable/disable, nor mask/unmask).

Comment: Thanks for all this information.  I haven't had a chance to try these things (I'm away from the system in question now), and it may take 24 hours to test each suggestion (that is, to discover whether packagekit does/doesn't reenable itself), but I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive overview.

Comment: It looks like — fingers crossed — `systemctl mask packagekit` has worked. Thanks again. Additional information added to question.